# how to set image in CircleAvatar of UserAccountsDrawerHeader of Navigation drawer in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter and I'm setting an image on navigation Drawer.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzbLY.png]

Comment: Post your code as text not image of it.

Comment: Also I don't understand why `c` has been tagged.

Comment: That is why you need to provide [mcve]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not  allowing me to submit  the code. that's why i posted Screenshot.

Comment: Then you must visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

just use Image.asset or Image.network as child of your CircleAvatar

Answer (score 0):

Just put ==> backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl)/Image.asset()
inside circular avtar.